# HUGE_VALF Undefined under Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I'm attempting to compile a code base originally intended for Linux / Unix platforms under Windows.  The code uses the HUGE_VALF variable seemingly without reference to a header that would define it.  The MS VC9 compiler I'm using on Windows throws:

> error C2065: 'HUGE_VALF' : undeclared identifier.

What is the recommended include file or way to define HUGE_VALF for Windows?  Math.h defines HUGE_VAL (the double), but not HUGE_VALF (as a float).

Comment: was there a `using namespace std` somewhere? Probably why there was no header

Comment: Which is it, C or C++? You're referencing the C header but you used the C++ tag...

Comment: Thanks for the catch, it's C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most implementations define `HUGE_VALF` to be `+Infinity`, but it is really only required to be a *"large positive value"*. A reasonable implementation:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) && !defined(HUGE_VALF)
# if defined(__cplusplus)
static float _X_huge_valf = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
#  define HUGE_VALF _X_huge_valf
# else
/* assumes Windows on a LE IEEE754 platform */
static union { unsigned int x; float y; } _X_huge_valf = { 0x7f800000 };
#  define HUGE_VALF (_X_huge_valf.y)
# endif /* __cplusplus */
#endif /* defined(WIN32) && !defined(HUGE_VALF) */
```

(You'll find lots of other oddities like this so I suggest you create a shim header for VC specific problems.)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the working code in your post, generally helpful comments, and the point about this not being the only VC specific issue I'll run into.  Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

How about just replacing `HUGE_VAL`* with *`_MAX` like so:

```
HUGE_VAL  => DOUBLE_MAX
HUGE_VALF => FLOAT_MAX
etc...
```

You could either define these for `_WIN32` only, or just replace the `HUGE_VAL`* stuff with the proper, standard replacement.

EDIT: MinGW-w64 (GCC) has these defines, probably they are C99 or C++0x things not (yet) in MSVC9. Maybe MSVC10 has them, though msdn seems to miss any information about the defines.

Comment: The code may depend on `HUGE_VALF` being `+Inf`, as I believe most implementations return that. Not that the code should rely on that...

Comment: I may have to go with this approach, but I think sixlettervariables has a point about it changing the value of this variable, which may be an issue.  Looking through the code base, I don't think it will be a problem, but since I'm not the original author, and I haven't spent much time in the code, I can't say that for sure.

Comment: well, the other option you have is using MinGW(-w64), which is GCC on Windows and it doesn't have this problem =)

Comment: +1, going the other compiler route if you have the option. I certainly loathe maintaining `config.h.w32`.